# GitHub Pages not loading API calls or saving changes

Tags: javascript, reactjs, api, github, github-pages

I deployed a react app on GitHub but it wasn't loading my API calls. Everything was working fine in VS Code so I tried googling some solutions but nothing worked. I tried updating the code on GitHub and in VS Code and then committing it didn't help or change anything. I even tried to make some minor changes to the code like changing the text on a button but even that wouldn't do anything when I viewed it on GitHub Pages even though it worked in VS Code.

Here's a link to the repository of the project on GitHub: https://github.com/Adomanwho/react-random/settings/pages

If you have any tips on how to solve this, I would appreciate it if you answered!

Comment: Your question doesn't reflect the error messages you received. In the future try to create a [mwe](https://stackoverflow.com/help/minimal-reproducible-example) and  you can also use [react in snippets](https://meta.stackoverflow.com/questions/338537/how-do-i-create-a-react-stack-snippet-with-jsx-support) if that helps. Your github link also 404's unless you're logged in as you. I took some time to find the actual github page and your related code, your error is that it doesn't like you requesting from http when using https. Your most recent build still has `'http://api.quotable.io/random'`

Comment: As the requested url. Try changing it to https like you have posted in the repo. Build it out again with the https and hopefully that fixes it :)